# JSON Parser Acts Differently

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

I am trying to parse the following string called result:

```
{
 "status":0,
 "id":"faxxxxx-1",
 "hypotheses":[
    {"utterance":"skateboard","confidence":0.90466744},
    {"utterance":"skate board"},
    {"utterance":"skateboarding"},
    {"utterance":"skateboards"},
    {"utterance":"skate bored"}
 ]
}
```

Using `obj = JSON.parse(result)` in Ruby 1.8 with the json gem.

The command in question is:

```
puts "#{obj['hypotheses'][0]}"
```

My old workstation (whose harddrive died) gave me:

```
{"utterance" => "skateboard", "confidence" => 0.90466744}
```

My current workstation gives me:

```
confidence0.90466744utteranceskateboard
```

The old workstation was not set up by me, so I don't know what kind of packages were installed, while this current one was.

Why is there a difference in the output of the exact same script? 
How can I make the current one look like the old one?

I am completely new to this btw.

Comment: The object you show appears to be a JSON structure, but that isn't the same as a Ruby string. Did you forget to show the delimiting single quotes that contain it and would make it a Ruby string?

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.8, `Hash#to_s` simply joins all of the elements together without spaces, equivalent to `to_a.flatten.join('')`.

In Ruby 1.9, `Hash#to_s` is an alias to `inspect` and produces well-formatted output.

To get the equivalent thing in both cases:

```
puts obj['hypotheses'][0].inspect
```

The same thing applies to Array.

Comment: Is there an easy ruby-ish way to reverse the output? 

From this method, I get:

{"confidence"=>0.90466744, "utterance"=>"skateboard"}

When I would like it the other way around. Ie utterance first.

Comment: If you mean to re-order the Hash, yes, you can always sort it before display. If you just want to sort it: `hash.sort` which converts it to an array of key/value pairs. To convert back to a Hash: `Hash[hash.sort]` should do it.